# windows xp Spirit pc faulty disc drawer

Tags: windows-xp

I have a windows xp Spirit pc, but cannot open the disc drawer. When "OPEN " is pressed, tries to open, but fails.I have had it open once, but after about 300 presses of button. Can someone please help.

Comment: Is there a small hole on the front panel near the drawer? Try sticking an unbend paper clip there and see if it opens when you push the paper clip.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the drawer on the CD or DVD drive. If so, the manufacturers usually have a small pinhole where you can push in a paperclip to open the drawer in the instance that it gets stuck. Whilst not a permanent solution to your problem (which would be to replace the drive because they are that cheap), it will get you working for now.

**Edit:** As stated in the comments, best to try this at first with the computer switched off - especially if there's still a CD or DVD in the drawer.

Comment: Also, please don't try this while the computer is powered on, especially if the drive is running. It tends to chew up the gears. (Likely something got stuck in a gear somewhere, actually... assuming it's a hardware issue.)